# What is undefined id in AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, mongodb, xmlhttprequest

I have two Tables in mongodb.

1. GstState
2. Store

In my `Store` form, I am trying to select state based on country by making an ajax call(for getting GstStates), but I am getting `id` as `undefined` in the JSON. I am not able to find out that catch.

Here is my code:

Any help would be appreciated.

**JavaScript:**

```
var countryHandle = document.querySelector('#store_country');
var stateHandle = document.querySelector('#store_gst_state_id');
countryHandle.addEventListener('change', function() {
      if (countryHandle.value !== "") {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/merchant_stores/find_states?
          country = ' + countryHandle.value);
          xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
              var states = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
              var states1 = states.sort((a, b) =>
                a.state_name.localeCompare(b.state_name))
              stateHandle.innerHTML = "";
              states1.forEach(function(state) {
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                var statename = document.createAttribute('value');
                statename.value = state.id;
                option.setAttributeNode(statename);
                var namewithcode = state.state_name.concat(" - ", state.state_code)
                var txt = document.createTextNode(namewithcode);
                option.appendChild(txt);
                stateHandle.appendChild(option);
              });
            }
          }
          xhr.send();
        }
      }, false)
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :state, "State *", :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <%= f.collection_select :gst_state_id, [], :id, :state_name %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :country, "Country *", :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" 
    %>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <%= f.select :country, options_for_select(Store::COUNTRY_CODES, 
    selected: @store.country),{}, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is fine.

Two reasons that `id` is `undefined`:

1. JSON response is empty (your serverside code is returning 0 rows from the table and sending that back to the client)
2. `id` property does not exist (check case sensitivity. Maybe you meant to put `Id`?)

To debug this, go to your browser's **Developer Tools -> Networking**. Then, monitor by triggering the event normally and investigate the response from the AJAX calls produced.